# Read a String from a txt file and store it into a char array in java

Tags: java, arrays, char, bufferedreader

I am new to java. I am trying to read a text file and store the variables it into an array char by char then apply Caesar Cipher encryption to it. However I am getting ejava.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4 on the line that says `if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j))`  If someone could help ,that would be great!

PROBLEM SOLVED*

```
public void passwordCaesaCipher() throws Exception {
        String str;
        int size = 0;
        char[] string1 = {};
        File f = new File("password.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String lowercase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
            string1 = str.toCharArray();
            size = str.length();
            System.out.println(size);
            System.out.println(string1);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
                    if (str.charAt(i) == lowercase.charAt(j)) {
                        System.out.print(str.charAt((j) % 26));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        
                    }

                }
            }
            System.out.println();

        }

    }
```

My text file has "abc" and I want it to be "bcd". However with my implementation I am getting abc.

Comment: What is the maximum size of the string? is it really 26 character?

Comment: @albertjtan There is no limit. However I put it as 26 because I want to perform modulo 26 operations since there are 26 alphabets.

Comment: but why str.charAt(j) then? shouldn't it be a list of alphabets? if you are using str, it will loop your string again which could possibly be less than 26

Comment: I appreciate your help! I am comparing list of alphabets to string from I get my text file.

Comment: @albertjtan I just did `  System.out.print(lowercase.charAt((j) % 26));` It fixed the error as you mentioned but my encryption doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: well if it's Caesar cipher algorithm you want, that my friend is easily googled on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the second loop helped me to achieve the correct answer. I forgot to add +1 to `System.out.print(lowercase.charAt((j) % 26));`. Because of that it was just printing itself . Correct solution is:  `System.out.print(lowercase.charAt((j+1) % 26));`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the length for the 2nd for loop that is 26. When the string that you read from the file is less than 26 of length, it will always result to index out of range.

Comment: I put it as 26 because I want to perform modulo 26 operations since there are 26 alphabets.

Comment: Just declare another string that has all the alphabet in there and use it with the 2nd for loop.

Comment: Okay just did that it solved the error but my encryption still doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit your question as to what is the output of your current implementation and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Just did it sorry for inconvenience